# prestashop 1.5 add cms page to top-bar menu

Tags: menu, prestashop

I'm new to Prestashop. I installed the 1.5 version and I found how to create "CMS" pages.

Now I would like to add these newly created pages to the main menu and I cannot find a simple way to do it.

Is there a good tutorial on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this date the above link is broken, so no reliable source there...

In my experience with Prestashop I've figured it's pretty hard to find good and straight to the point info (especially compared with WordPress for example). So here is my answer:

- In back-end go to Modules and find the "Top horizontal menu"(blocktopmenu) module (it should be under "Front Office Features" category, or you can also use search).
- If it's not installed just install and activate it.
- After that you should go to "Configure" under plugin's administration links.
  You should be able to add the pages from choosing the ones in the left panel and adding them to the right (which would add them to the Top Menu).

You can also add your custom links in this plugin's back-end in the lower section called "Add Menu Top Link" by clicking "Add" button and then adding the link from the left to the right as described above.

Hope this helps. Have Fun!